# Курс - Jonas Schmedtmann's Asynchronous coding - Chaining Promises - restcountries issue - не могу вернуть данные из объекта, на второй вызов функции

Tags: javascript, объекты, асинхронность, callback, return

Всем привет, у меня есть проблема достать ключ из объекта, который получается после еще одного использования callback функции по цепи:

```
'use strict';

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-country');
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector('.countries');
/////////////////////////////
const renderCountry = function (data, className = '') {
  const html = `
  <article class="country ${className}">  
  <img class="country__img" src="${data.flags.png}" />
    <div class="country__data">
      <h3 class="country__name">${data.name.official}</h3>
      <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
      <p class="country__row"><span></span> ${(
        +data.population / 1000000
      ).toFixed(1)} millions people</p>
      <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${Object.values(
        data.languages
      )}</p>
      <p class="country__row"><span></span>${Object.keys(data.currencies)}</p>
</article>`;
  countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', html);
  countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
const getCountryData = function (country) {
  // Country 1
  fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      renderCountry(data[0]);
      console.log(data);
      const neighbour = data[0].borders[0];
      if (!neighbour) return;
      // Country 2
      return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/${neighbour}`);
    })
    .then(responce => responce.json())
    .then(data => renderCountry(data, 'neighbour'));
};

getCountryData('portugal');
};
```

Итак проблема в том , что для соседской страны по вызову функции renderCountry(data, 'neighbour') (где neighbour это класс для css), у меня возникает ошибка:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'png')
    at renderCountry (Asynchronous.js:43:47)
    at Asynchronous.js:122:19
```

На всякий случай приложу html и css, если захотите повторить, может у меня беды с машиной. Мне очень нужен ответ на вопрос, какой конкретно командой мне достать из объекта флаги в таком случае? или может как-то исправить функцию?
HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="Asynchronous.js"></script>
    <title>Asynchronous JavaScript</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <main class="container">
      <div class="countries"></div>
     
      <div class="images"></div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

и Css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.countries {
  /* margin-bottom: 8rem; */
  display: flex;

  font-size: 2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.country {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  width: 30rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.neighbour::before {
  content: 'Neighbour country';
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4rem;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888;
}

.neighbour {
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(1rem);
  margin-left: 0;
}

.country__img {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 17rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.7rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.7rem;
}

.country__data {
  padding: 2.5rem 3.75rem 3rem 3.75rem;
}

.country__name {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.country__region {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #888;
}

.country__row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.country__row span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.btn-country {
  border: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: orangered;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.images {
  display: flex;
}

.images img {
  display: block;
  width: 80rem;
  margin: 4rem;
}

.images img.parallel {
  width: 40rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border: 3rem solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо иногда в данных нет инфморации о флаге (ключ flags).
Можно проверить вот так:

```
<img class="country__img" src="${data.flags?.png || ''}">
```

В случае, если ключа flags не сущетсвует, `src` оставлять пустым, или заменить на шаблонную картинку.

Также можно проверить наличие ключа перед выводом картинки и если отсутствует, то вообще не отображать:

```
let img = 'flags' in data ? `<img class='country__img' src='${data.flags.png}'>` : "";
const html = `...
             ${img}
             ...`;
```

Comment: Тут еще произошло небольшое недоразумение, в случае второго возращения функции мы получаем массив данных, а не объект как я понимал, и следуя этой логике нужно тупо выделить еще раз что нужен первый элемент массива :

 return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/alpha/${neighbour}`);
    })
    .then(responce => responce.json())
    .then(data => renderCountry(data (ВОТ ТУТ надо указать data[0] а не дата просто.) , 'neighbour'));
};

Comment: ну да, отлично, что сами разобрались)